# Programming the Baofeng UV-5x3

Tags: baofeng, chirp

When using CHIRP to Program my Baofeng UV-5x3
I click "download from radio"
There is a model "5x", but no "5x3" to choose from.
What can I do?
Mark

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be fully supported by [CHIRP-next](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/ChirpNextBuild) builds:

https://github.com/kk7ds/chirp/blob/master/tests/Python3_Driver_Testing.md

So, you need to use CHIRP-next, instead of the legacy CHIRP.